# HAR file reading error: log.entries is expected to be an array

Tags: parsing, google-chrome-devtools, har

I have generated a HAR file from an Android Emulator on Appetize.io. When I try to read the file in Chrome Dev tools I get the following error:

`log.entries is expected to be an array`.

You can find a sample HAR file here: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qnXLvUFe).

How can I fix this file?

Comment: 1) If you export a HAR from devtools you'll see "entries" **inside** "log", but your file has it as a sibling. 2) Your file is missing "bodySize" inside each "request", which is required by devtools. You can fix it manually or report the issue to the developers of the emulator.

Comment: Thanks, I already reported it. They are trying to fix this by the end of the week.